# Raspberry Pi 3B+ Wlan issues

Tags: connection, wifi

I've bought a Raspberry Pi 3B+(more precisely: the starter kit ABOX Raspberry Pi 3 B+ Kit) and installed Raspbian on it. I connected the Raspberry with the internet by using it's wlan adapter and I tried it also with a Fritzbox Wlan Stick N. The problem is that whenever I need to use the internet connection on both devices both are slowed down dramatically.

The strange thing is that my smartphone seems not to be affected nor affects any of the other connections. This only happens when my main computer (Windows 10) and my Raspberry are trying to use some service on the internet at the same time

Can anyone help me with this? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my RPI, and it turned out to be the Power Management feature.
You can try disabling it:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

If it worked, you can [add this command to your rc.local file](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md)

Comment: It didn't solve the problem entirely, but it got better. Thank you. The problem is stil there but not as bad as it was before.